# Create a rolling window of inputs with forEach and reduce in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following data-set:

```
const data = [
  ["opens", "opens", "opens"], //opens of stock prices
  ["closes", "closes", "closes"], //closes of stock prices
  ["highs", "highs", "highs"], //highs of stock prices
  ["lows", "lows", "lows"] //close of stock prices
];
```

I have a `forEach` function that calls another function with the input of `res`. I am trying to create a rollingInput to feed to my neural network. Right now its only accepting one candle of input for each output. I want to create a rolling input of for this example 5.

```
this.opens.forEach((x, index) => {

    let res = data.reduce((acc, list, idx, arr) => {
        if (idx >= list.length)
            return acc;

        return [...acc, ...arr.map(x => x[idx])];
    }, []);

    console.log(res);
    this.function(res);
});
```

How can I make sure that when the `forEach` loop is going that `res` is actually a sliding window with the newest array being fed last?

I am looking for an output like such
`[opens[-5], closes[-5], highs[-5], low[-5],opens[-4], closes[-4], highs[-4], low[-4],opens[-3], closes[-3], highs[-3], low[-3], opens[-3], closes[-2], highs[-2], low[-2], opens[-2], opens, [-1], closes[-1], highs[-1], low[-1], opens[0], closes[0], highs[0], low[0]]`

then the next output should start at [0] and end at [5]

not sure if that is the proper way to do it and also not sure how I would cut off the negative values as obviously -5 doesnt exist.

Answer (score 1):

You have `arr.map(x => x[idx])` which I assume corresponds to `data["opens"].map(x => x[idx])`

Instead of `data["opens"].map(x => x[idx])` use the index value of map to get all values:

data["opens"].map((value, index)=>{
return [data["opens"][index], data["closes"][index], data["Highs"][index], data["lows"][index]]
})

Comment: What about if I just go `
return [...acc, ...arr.map(x => x[index])];
`

Comment: I thought you want them in time order... the way you have it the outer loop loops by data type... the outer loop should iterate over time index and the innermost loop should iterate the ttpes

Comment: `this.opens.forEach((x, index) => {
      const candleInput = this.networkInput.reduce(
        (array, item) => [...array, item[index]],
        []
      );
      const candle = this.data.reduce(
        (array, item) => [...array, item[index]],
        []
      );
      let rollingInput = this.networkInput.reduce((acc, list, idx, arr) =>
      {
          if (idx >= 5 )
              return acc;
        return [...acc, arr.map((x, index)=>{ return [this.opens[index], this.closes[index], this.highs[index],this.lows[index]] })]
      }, []);
this.function(rollingInput);
    })`

Comment: Yeah something like that

Comment: Yeah it works. But I need them to all be in one array rather then separate ones for each call. I tried spreading them w/ ... but it wont allow it? Any suggestions?

Comment: With youre suggestion it is [[opens, closes, highs lows],[opens, closes, highs lows],[opens, closes, highs lows],[opens, closes, highs lows],[opens, closes, highs lows]

when it should be [opens, closes, highs lows, opens, closes, highs lows, etc]

Comment: there's also return acc.concat(this.opens[index]).concat(this.closes[index]).concat(this.highs[index]).concat(this.lows[index]]) which is non mutating like the spread operator (...). Also acc.push which you can use like that but that is mutating. More mutating vs nonmutating here https://lorenstewart.me/2017/01/22/javascript-array-methods-mutating-vs-non-mutating/

Comment: I mean acc.concat(arr.map((x, index)=>{ return [this.opens[index], this.closes[index], this.highs[index],this.lows[index]] })) or acc.push(arr.map((x, index)=>{ return [this.opens[index], this.closes[index], this.highs[index],this.lows[index]] }))